# is it always possible to transform any nth order ODE in a system of n first order ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I mean, the addition of *n-1* variables corresponding to the second, third ... n^th derivative of the original one seems quite straightforward and generic, and I don't see particular caveats... nevertheless most texts I found online say "for most nth order ODEs" or "generically", so I was wondering whether there was any need for a more rigorous proof for complete equivalence or if there are some special cases for which this equivalence does not fully hold.
Also, a counterexample would be particularly helpful.
I have an engineering background hence a practical approach to math and I am not used to "traps" or corner cases.

Thanks all! this is my first question over here so please be merciful

Answer (score 1):

An $n$th order ODE is an equation of the form
$$
f(x,y,y', \ldots, y^{(n)}) = 0
$$
Now, the fact that the ODE is $n$th order means that $f$ must actually depend on $y^{(n)}$.

Now, suppose that $f$ is $C^1$. The fact that $f$ depends on $y^{(n)}$ means
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{(n)}} \neq 0
$$
By the implicit function theorem, there exists a $C^1$ function $g$ such that
$$
f(x, y, y', \ldots , g(x, y, y', \ldots, y^{(n - 1)})) = 0
$$
Informally, this means $y^{(n)} = g(x, y, y', \ldots, y^{(n - 1)}$. Even more informally, we can say that $y^{(n)}$ depends only on $x, y, y', \ldots, y^{(n-1)}$.

Now, define $z_0 = y$, $z_{k} = y^{(k)}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n - 1$, and let $z_n = g(x,y, y' , \ldots, y^{(n - 1)})$.

Then we have the $n$ first order equations: $z_{k - 1}' = z_{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n - 1$ and $z_{n-1}' = g(x,z_0, z_1 , \ldots, z_{n - 1})$.

You can check that $f(x,y,y', \ldots, y^{(n)}) = 0$ if and only if the $n$ first order $z$ equations are satisfied.

To summarize, if the $z$ equations are satisfied, then we'll have $f(x, z_0, \ldots, z_n) = 0$ by construction. If the $y$ equation is satisfied, then we can apply the implicit function theorem to solve for $y_n$, define $z_k = y^{(k)}$, and form the $n$ first order equations relating the $z_k$.

Comment: To be more careful, we are only allowed to use the implicit function theorem if we know $f(\ldots) = 0$ is true for some point in $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$ and, at that point, the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y^{(n)}$ doesn't vanish.

Answer (score 0):

It is as you say completely straightforward. The point is that it is equivalent to consider an $n$-th order ODE on say $\mathbb R$, or a first order ODE on $\mathbb R^n$.

But there are differences between a first order ODE on $\mathbb R$ and eg a first order ODE on $\mathbb R^3$. For instance, you cannot have periodic trajectories in dimension one, you need at least two dimensions. More complicated phenomena also only appear in dimension starting from 3.

Comment: thanks! I did not understand the point related to periodicity. can't we take the solutions of $\dot y = \sin t$ as example of periodic, yet single dimensional, orbits?

Comment: I mean autonomous ODEs. Non autonomous ODEs can also always be written as autonomous ODEs in more variable

Comment: thanks again. you mean by introducing a new variable $x_{N+1}$ and a new equation $\dot x_{N+1} = 1$ and replacing all occurrencies of $t$ with $x_{N+1}$? do you have any references that discuss the physical insights, if any, of this additional dimension? seems like we are modeling a changing velocity vector field as "slices" stack one onto the other and we are forcing the orbit to traverse these slices as time goes by...